# PHP - pg_connect() cannot translate host name to address (via VPN)

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

I'm trying to connect via PHP to a remote PgSQL server, inside my VPN.

Here is the code (a simple script that extracts information from a table that contains a list of users):

```
$query = "SELECT name, surname FROM test_table WHERE id=$1";
$link   = pg_Connect("host=named.host.inside.my.VPN.network dbname=testdb user=username password=password") or die('DB Connection failed');
if ($link){
    $select = pg_prepare($link, "my_query", $query);
    $select = pg_execute($link, "my_query", array(1));  //retrieve user with id == 1
    if($select){
        while ($row = pg_fetch_row($select)){
            echo "User 1: " . $row[0] . " " . $row[1];
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Select error! - " . pg_last_error($link);
    }
}
else{
    echo "Link error - " . pg_last_error($link);
}
```

I'm running this script inside XAMPP (Windows 7 as OS) and the PgSQL server is an AmazonRDS, reachable via a named-host like  `named.host.inside.my.VPN.network`.

If I make a ping to this host, cmd shows up the correct IP address of the server and if I add this IP address to "hosts" file PHP correctly resolves it and doesn't die. If don't add the row "123.45.67.89 named.host.inside.my.VPN.network" into the "hosts" file , the script execution gives this output:

> Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could
>   not translate host name "named.host.inside.my.VPN.network" to address: Unknown
>   server error in C:\xampp\htdocs\filename.php on line 6 DB Connection
>   failed

My question is: is there a way to let pg_connect() resolve "named.host.inside.my.VPN.network" domain **WITHOUT** adding it to file "hosts" (considering it is correctly translated/reachable via ping)?

Comment: Use the IP address in the `pg_connect` call? Either your OS's DNS resolver must be able to find it or your must use the IP. If you can't add it to hosts, fix your VPN setup so it exports internal-name servers properly. Either way, this is just sysadmin stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart the httpd (apache) service.

I'm having the same problems as you, maybe it's the same cause.
Somehow the postgresql plugin seems to be confused after startup.
Entering the IP in 'hosts' is working, but DNS lookup not.
I am running Archlinux with php 5.5.16/pgsql 9.3.5.
To restart, I do 'systemctl restart httpd' but you'll problably have to dig in the services.msc tool.